# agregar fila al datagridview y ubicarla en la primera posición

Tags: c#

Al agregar una fila a un datagridview, necesito que la nueva fila insertada se ubique en la primera posición, siempre que sea nueva, se agregue en la primera posición.

Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías compartir el código de como cargas los datos y en base a eso se te puede ayudar, Saludos!

Comment: Agrego las filas por el metodo Add() del datagridview, ejemplo: datagridView.Rows.Add(txtNombre.Text, txtDireccion.Text, txtTelefono.Text);, pero se me agregan una detrás de la otra, lo que quisiera es que al momento de agregar una nueva fila, la misma se ponga en la primera posición del datagridview.

Comment: Puedes crear una lista donde hagas un sort cada vez que agregues un item nuevo, luego eso lo pasas a un DataTable y lo asignas al DataSource del DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `Insert`

```
DataGridView.Rows.Insert(0, txtNombre.Text, txtDireccion.Text, txtTelefono.Text);
```

Donde 0 indicas que siempre inserte en la primera posición del DataGridView, Espero haber entendido tu pregunta y te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que estaba buscando.